# Fill in blanks in multiple columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have about 50 columns in my spreadsheet and around 5000 rows. In these 50 columns, there is either "TRUE" or it is blank. What's a shortcut to changing all of the blank cells to "FALSE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Search-and-replace**, searching **by cell** for empty quotes `""`, replacing with `FALSE`.

Some versions of Excel may require a different expression to target the empty cells; I've always found it through experimentation and the local built-in help facility.

You can also **Export** to **CSV**, open that file in a text editor, do the search-and-replace there, and then load the CSV into a new spreadhseet....

Answer (score 2):

First, select the area you'd like to modify.  In the Home tab of the ribbon is the "Find & Select" menu; click "Go To Special", select "Blanks" and click OK.

If you'd like, the keyboard shortcut is [Alt] + [H] + [F] + [D] + [S] + [K]

Type in the value you'd like to be in the selected cells, hold down [CTRL] and press [Enter].  The value will fill in the empty cells.